# first layer tearing

Tags: ultimaker-cura, anet-a8, adhesion

I have an Anet A8 and have a problem with my first layer. I printed nice prints but starting today the first layer is tearing in the middle:

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! You don't state what filament you're using or any of your settings. This looks to be a heat problem ... as in too much of it.

Comment: Hi,  I'm using pla and the bed is 60 and the head 210. Strange thing is I didnt change anything of the settings and suddenly it started doing this

Comment: 210° is a bit hot for PLA ... you should try and turn it down some, like into the 190° arena. The bed at 60° should be okay, I'd think.

Comment: 210 is very reasonable for PLA. 190 will heavily limit the speed you can print. I suspect it's a bed height problem.

Comment: Strange, It was indeed a bed problem, could have sworn I checked it. A well thnx anyway :)

Comment: @Zeepblok: Glad that helped! I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The great pics really help with the answerability of this question. From how catastrophic the failure is, and how it's clearly independent of any specialty needs for the particular print such as tiny bed-adhesion contacts, sharp overhangs, bridges, etc. this is definitely not a problem with temperature. Different people recommend different temperatures for PLA, but I find that 210°C works well for me, and if you go much lower you'll hit problems getting the needed extrusion rate for anything but slow print speeds.

I've seen nearly this exact phenomenon before, so I knew it was probably a matter of the bed being too high, blocking extrusion of the first layer and forcing what little material can escape out to the sides of the nozzle, then tearing into it when the next adjacent line is laid out.

If I didn't know that, though, I'd still start looking for a source of the problem that's related to extrusion rate. Something was clearly wrong with getting the right amount of material in the right space, which indicates to me that there's either too much material (overextrusion/wrong filament diameter selected) or too little space (bed to high).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be the exact opposite. My bed was too low (as in too far from the hotend). All the above mentioned aside, I did also drop the flow rate on the brim and initial layer by roughly 2-3 %. Now it prints perfectly again. (your mileage may vary)